# Show intital content from the bottom and load more rows from database on scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to start from the bottom of a div on page load(not via scrolling to the bottom) ?

show the latest n messages,
and if the user scrolls up load past messages.

```
<div id="myDiv">content going here</div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myDiv').scrollTop($('#myDiv')[0].scrollHeight);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe You should use native JavaScript solution?

```
window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);
```

You can takie the `x-coord` and `y-coord` coordinates from jQuery [`.position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/).

Example code:

```
<div id="myDiv">content going here</div>
<a class="xxxx" href="#">click here</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.xxxx').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var position = $('#myDiv').position();
        window.scrollTo(position.left, position.top);
    });
</script>
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/o8rsg5sz/

Comment: any example like in context of my question, how will u describe this in code?

Comment: if am using this should the div have absolute position ?

Comment: @user4853991 I have added example code and JSFiddle link. Check it out.

Comment: yours is working, but why this edited version does not works ?? 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devaaroon11/o8rsg5sz/2/)

Comment: okay but your fiddle shows how to scroll top, i wanna scroll to the bottom how to do that ?
in my fiddle 'a' is on the top but but at window.scroll i have left && bottom.

Comment: Because `.position()` don't return `bottom` variable. You should use other ways: https://jsfiddle.net/o8rsg5sz/3/

Comment: this one seems to scroll as i wanted, just one more thing how to load content when i scroll up

Comment: Well... this question should be for another post, because we are going a little off-topic (I answered Your question) and You should use google more often. Try to find a solution on Your own first.

Comment: well, okay
thanx brother